# What is the best aproach for coding in a slow compilation environment

Tags: c++, productivity, development-environment

I used to coding in C# in a TDD style - write/or change a small chunk of code, re-compile in 10 seconds the whole solution, re-run the tests and again. Easy...

That development methodology worked very well for me for a few years, until a last year when I had to go back to C++ coding and it really feels that my productivity has dramatically decreased since. The C++ as a language is not a problem - I had quite a lot fo C++ dev experience... but in the past.

My productivity is still OK for a small projects, but it gets worse when with the increase of the project size and once compilation time hits 10+ minutes it gets really bad. And if I find the error I have to start compilation again, etc. That is just purely frustrating.

Thus I concluded that in a small chunks (as before) is not acceptable - any recommendations how can I get myself into the old gone habit of coding for an hour or so, when reviewing the code manually (without relying on a fast C# compiler), and only recompiling/re-running unit tests once in a couple of hours.

With a C# and TDD it was very easy to write a code in a evolutionary way - after a dozen of iterations whatever crap I started with was ending up in a good code, but it just does not work for me anymore (in a slow compilation environment).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078409/what-is-the-best-aproach-for-coding-in-a-slow-compilation-environment These should probably be merged/in one place.

Comment: See laso http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373142/what-techniques-can-be-used-to-speed-up-c-compilation-times for speeding up C++ compile times.

Comment: Start a [swordfight](http://xkcd.com/303/). ;p

Comment: The last time I used C++ in earnest, using pre-compiled headers cut down compilation time by a factor four.

Answer (score 16):

Several things come to my mind:

1. Make use of ***distributed compilation***. You can do this with GCC ("distCC"?) or VC ([Xoreax' IncrediBuild](http://incredibuild.com) is not exactly cheap, but worth every cent spent on it.).
2. ***Split your project*** into dynamically loaded libraries, and carefully try to minimize the dependencies on them. Smaller executables link much faster.
3. Program against ***small test projects*** rather than the whole big application.
4. Employ template-meta programming to ***perform algorithms at compile-time***. Yes, this will actually increase compilation times, but it will also decrease turnarounds needed for testing: If it compiles fine, it's done.
5. Invest in ***hardware***. More CPU kernels (in your machine or in others) will do wonder with distributed compilation, and lots of memory plus a fast disk (SSD instead of HDD) will help a lot to. If you have a 64bit system and obscene amounts of RAM, compiling on a RAM disk might provide an incredible speed boost.

Comment: compiler caches are actually a better idea than distributed compilation in my experience.

Comment: Speaking of RAM disk vs. SSD, I was quite surprised that it didn't bring so much increase in compile speed. My current project (Java on Android) compiles from clean state in ~45 seconds from SSD and in ~40 seconds from RAM disk (and the whole toolchain is in RAM disk, not just sources). Not a dramatic increase, I'd say.

Answer (score 10):

Another technical solution not yet mentioned by others is switching to Solid State Drives instead of regular hard drives. In a previous project I worked on, SSDs brought down build times from the range of 30 minutes to 3.

Of course, they are costly. For your boss, calculate the price of lost developer time against the price of the one-time investment. The investment probably pays for itself in a few months.

Comment: That's interesting. That says 90% of build time is I/O disk latency.

Comment: I haven't seen a 90% decrease, but a substantial one.  It doesn't seem to speed up compilation, but it definitely speeds up linking.  If you're making small changes to a large project (so there isn't much compilation in a change), and relinking, you might well get this.  (This is Visual Studio 2008, using C++.)

Comment: @David: Yeah, or `ar`. I see a big difference between built-in disk and USB disk.

Comment: This is a good idea. Also, mounting a part of RAM on your filesystem would work fast, and it's cheap.

Comment: If disk IO is the problem, then lots of RAM for the disk cache should also help. And perhaps an aggressively cacheing and write-combining filesystem like ZFS.

Comment: Ramdisk is even faster (and cheaper).

Comment: "If compiling takes even 15 seconds, programmers will get bored while the compiler runs and switch over to reading The Onion, which will suck them in and kill hours of productivity." => [Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html)

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: Well, DUHHH!  Think about it.  The compiler has to read in every character of every source and include file.  That means it has to go out to the disk fairly often, move the head, wait for the head to move, wait for the disk to spin around to the sector of interest, read the sector of interest at a rate determined by the magnetic density of the disk and the angular rate of the disk, possibly repeat the whole process because that sector read was to find out where the REAL sector of interest is on the disk...  Disk I/O is freaking EXPENSIVE.

Comment: @John: Yeah, a well-written compiler should (IMHO) be I/O bound.

Answer (score 3):

More planning, code in bigger chunks, write integration tests instead of unit-tests and run the build + test suite overnight.

Answer (score 3):

Long compilation times are a problem sometimes, but the already mentioned modularisation can help overcome that (mostly).

Far more serious is being stuck in an environment where you cannot compile at all, where every code change has to be submitted to another department on another continent for application to the test/development environment, a process that can take days to complete.

I'm now working in such an environment, and this system has already cost me over a week of time (and the project only has budget for 4 weeks total time before the money runs out) just to get the initial version of our changes installed (and then they made mistakes which cause part of the files to not be picked up by the application server, so we're looking at several more days of delays).
Each minor change now (say we find something in testing that needs fixing, like a missed error condition) can cause a delay of another day or more.

In such conditions you try to make as certain as you can that there are no errors whatsoever before even trying to get your code compiled.
It feels almost like I'm back to mainframe programming, where we had 5 minutes of CPU time per month available for all compile and test work.

Comment: Boy, that's a situation from hell. I do remember the mainframe days. We did a lot of "desk checking" of code. It's amazing how much got done that way, such as endless simulations of flights to the moon.

Answer (score 3):

I can easily remember when builds took a long time. Some mitigating approaches:

- Build the system by combining libraries or dlls. That way, when you modify some code, the only part that needs to be recompiled is your part.
- The number of points in the code you need to edit to implement a feature not only effects how much editing you have to do, but the frequency with which you put in bugs, amplifying the compile-debug-edit-compile loop. Anything that reduces the redundancy of the code, such as DRY, helps.
- If you are in the debugger, and can edit, recompile, and continue without leaving the debugger, that is really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

10+ minutes for a compile? Seriously?

Are you using an IDE that does incremental building (e.g. Eclipse)? If not, you probably should be, it'll do the basic compiling in seconds rather than minutes.

Or are you talking about integration stuff, where you need to build the entire app to test your change? If so, look at smaller tests to ensure the major bugs are out of your code before having to do the full build.

Comment: 10mins is small. I've worked for a project that took an hour to compile and link from scratch on a single-core machine, PCHs and all. Of course, except for automatic release builds nobody would build it on just one processor core, but still... If you had to change something in a header that's included just about everywhere (string manipulation, error handling), you could go nuts.

Comment: +1 for sbi. 10 minutes is nothing for a medium-size C++ project. Heck, I am currently working on a mainly C# project and that takes way more than 10 minutes to build.

Comment: Used to work (years ago) on a system that took, for a complete build, 48 hours to compile.
Of course a full build was only ever started on friday evening, hopefully to be done when we got back to the office on monday.
We instead built small modules as needed (say a single DLL).

Comment: -1 to all the comments above if I could +1 to TrueDub. Yes, if you are recompiling everything then it can take a very long time. However, if any thought at all is given to dependency management then 10 hour entire recompile projects can have incremental recompiles in less than a minute be the norm. You all should be ashamed of yourselves wasting your employers time waiting for your recompiles when applying a bit of intelligence will save vast amounts of time.

Comment: @Dunk: have you ever _been_ in such a big project? I have, and being responsible for a lot of low-level stuff that was used virtually everywhere in the project (logging, error handling, string encoding stuff...) was a major pain in the donkey. Besides that, some of those DLLs took several minutes to (_incrementally_) link alone, and linking the monolithic Release executable took >10mins. Even with lightning-fast distributed compilation that makes for abysmally slow debug-edit-compile cycles.

Comment: And if you work in a small shop that happens to sit on a several-MLoC project, then that means that a considerable part of the code is old, started out a decade ago as multiple small projects, where compilation speed never was an issue, and the dependency management is abominably bad. So are you going to tell such a company to throw all this away and spend another decade re-writing it?

Comment: @sbi: Yes I have worked on 100+ developer projects with several million lines of code and the key to not wasting 100's of man hours every week was managing the dependencies and managing the interfaces. If you were creating low level stuff that was used by everyone then you should have nailed down those interfaces VERY EARLY in the process. Then it should have taken a near act of god to change those interfaces since it will cause 10's of hours of wasted developer time.

Comment: @sbi: As for throwing away the code. I guess it is okay to waste hours (probably more) twiddling thumbs every week recompiling rather than fix the problem. Fixing the problem does not mean throwing everything away.

Comment: @Dunk: It was a small company, with less than a dozen developers working on a multi-MLoC project. That's _very_ different from hundreds of developers doing so: you cannot re-write _anything_ from scratch, because you'd need years to do so. As much as I hated the idea, investing in distributed compilation was economically feasible, re-writing wasn't. Oh, and I inherited those interfaces. `:-x` I wasn't there a decade ago, when they were thought up. (I changed a lot of that code to employ TMP, to find more errors at compilation, and less in the field.)

Answer (score 2):

First, why does it take so long to compile in the first place?

- Does your environment (IDE, make, whatever) support incremental builds?  Make sure that you are only recompiling the changes, rather than the whole thing.
- If you have a multi-core machine, your IDE may support parallel compilation.  I know for a fact that Visual Studio does that.  Apparently so does gcc.  So get a better machine, and enable parallel compilation.
- Consider using precompiled headers.
- If you try all that, and compilation is still slow, review your code.  Look for unnecessary dependencies.  Are you including a header where a forward declaration would be sufficient?  Consider using the PIMPL idiom to reduce dependency on headers.

If after all of this your build time is still slow, then break up the problem: create many small test projects and work on each individually.  Make sure you have a automated nightly build system that does a fresh checkout, builds everything, and runs all the unit tests automatically.

Finally, if it still takes you a long time to test your changes, then put more thought into them.  Be sure to do a diff in your version control system and carefully review all the changes before testing.  In short, this is very much like embedded systems development, where the turnaround time for a test is long, and your ability to examine the state of the system is limited.

This leads me to another thought: instrument your code to use logging.  This way you may be able to see what the problem is without rebuilding and re-running a dozen times.

Comment: I'm not sure if GCC supports parallel compiles so much as the fact that make or similar tools will start several copies of GCC if you tell it too.

Comment: +1 for PIMPL.  I worked on a project where the build times got out of control.  In that project, I took no care on how many other headers were included in each header.  On my next project, I made it a point to minimize this by making extensive use of PIMPL. The build times continue to be great even though the second project is probably twice the size of the first.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a multi-prong approach:

1) Faster build systems. As many cores/ram/fast disk as you can afford. For larger C++ projects you'll find that disk is often a limiter, so make sure you have fast ones.

2) More modularization of the project. Break stuff up so that changes can't easily cause full re-compiles of everything. Frankly, push as much basic stuff as possible into separate dll/so files so that part of the project can be completely divorced from the rest.

3) Incremental builds/distributed builds/caching as appropriate to your environment. On some systems, distcc (distributed building) and ccache (caching of partially built stuff) can save a lot of compile time.

4) Make sure your build can be well parallelized. In a makefile environment especially, it's not hard to get into a situation where you've accidentally setup the Makefiles such that you can't do parallel building.

Answer (score 0):

Extensive logging and internal validation has been helpful for long turnaround times. Once your build is done, a single run can reveal a large set of possible issues at once.

When dealing with rather complex algorithms or bookkeeping, it can be helpful to include a highly simplified version in parallel with the 'real' one. In any run, you have useful reference data included.

Answer (score 0):

What @sbi and @Michael Kohne said.

Spend time and energy on the build process itself.  Once upon a time we had a stately, mature product that took more than an hour for a full build.  Much time and energy was spent fixing what the build dependencies claimed to be, and then later, fixing/reducing what they actually were.  Build time dropped to ~30 minutes.

Changing build tools dropped it more. For a multi-part project, 'scons' can do all compiles before doing any links.  'make' using multiple makefiles does one single project's compiles before that project's links, then moves on.

That brought us to the point that all the individual compile commands could be done massively parallel.  'distcc' on slow machines, make/scons -j8 on multicore machines.  That brought full builds down to a handful of minutes.

In a different light, create an automated nightly build process.  That way if something problematic gets committed to your source repository, the first person to arrive at work, see and fix the problem, may prevent multiple people from (re)doing multiple failed builds.